# Do I have to configure a server with hardware RAID?

Tags: 14.04, server, raid

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 an [HP ProLiant ML350 Generation 6 (G6)](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04286582.pdf) server, that used run windows, which appears to have RAID controller:
[image]

The Ubuntu [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) says:

> Hardware-RAID: A special controller used to build RAID. Hardware RAID
>   is generally faster, and does not place load on the CPU, and hardware
>   RAID can be used with any OS

But I'm not certain if this means the hardware will do things automatically, or if there's something I have to configure.

When I check:

```
root@webserver:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
```

It doesn't appear as though anything is there.

This is the first server I've ever configured a server, and I'll confess I was ignorant to what RAID was when I installed the OS, so my question is do I have to configure RAID now or is the hardware doing everything automatically? If I still need to configure it, how do I do that without re-installing the OS?

Answer (score 1):

If it is hardware raid, then it is already taking care of it and you can see the configuration in the bios raid utility ( changing the hardware raid configuration is usually destructive, so you will need to reinstall ).  Look for something in the bios POST screens that mention pressing some key for the raid utility.  If this is the case you will only see a single drive ( /dev/sda ).  `/proc/mdstat` normally only lists *software* raid arrays, which you can configure if, and only if you desire ( and the simplest way to do so is to reinstall ).  If you see multiple drives in the system ( /dev/sdb, etc ), then you don't have hardware raid.